# Making a table with smaller tables from other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

[I'm using Excel Pro 2013]

I have a sheet called '11', where I have a table in cells P41:S43

```
1     2      3     4
5     6      7     8
9     10     11    12
13    14     15    16
```

From sheet '12' I want to reproduce the same table (as in if I modify the table in '11', it gets updated in '12'). One way of doing this is manually, by using a formulas such as:

```
='11'!P41   ='11'!Q41   ='11'!R41
='11'!P42   ='11'!Q42   ='11'!R42
='11'!P43   ='11'!Q43   ='11'!R43
```

There are many other sheets (from 1:11) with each having a different table in the same cells (P41:S41). I want to have a sheet called 'All tables' where I have a big table with all individual tables put together. For tables 1:4 in 'All tables' sheet would look like this

```
1   ='1'!P41    ='1'!Q41    ='1'!R41    ='1'!S41
1   ='1'!P42    ='1'!Q42    ='1'!R42    ='1'!S42
1   ='1'!P43    ='1'!Q43    ='1'!R43    ='1'!S43
1   ='1'!P44    ='1'!Q44    ='1'!R44    ='1'!S44
2   ='2'!R38    ='2'!S38    ='2'!T38    ='2'!U38
2   ='2'!R39    ='2'!S39    ='2'!T39    ='2'!U39
2   ='2'!R40    ='2'!S40    ='2'!T40    ='2'!U40
2   ='2'!R41    ='2'!S41    ='2'!T41    ='2'!U41
3   ='3'!Q40    ='3'!R40    ='3'!S40    ='3'!T40
3   ='3'!Q41    ='3'!R41    ='3'!S41    ='3'!T41
3   ='3'!Q42    ='3'!R42    ='3'!S42    ='3'!T42
3   ='3'!Q43    ='3'!R43    ='3'!S43    ='3'!T43
4   ='4'!P38    ='4'!Q38    ='4'!R38    ='4'!S38
4   ='4'!P39    ='4'!Q39    ='4'!R39    ='4'!S39
4   ='4'!P40    ='4'!Q40    ='4'!R40    ='4'!S40
4   ='4'!P41    ='4'!Q41    ='4'!R41    ='4'!S41
```

Which in practice I achieved by writing always the first line of each group and then dragging the formulas down three rows e.g.,

```
    ='1'!P41    ='1'!Q41    ='1'!R41    ='1'!S41
```

When I would done with the 4 first rows, I would have to change the first row from referencing sheet '1' to sheet '2' and then dragging down three rows (for achieving rows 5-8).

Is there any way where I can achieve the same result (all tables from sheets in one super table) without so much manual work? My idea would be something like this:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'";A2;"'!P41"))
              =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'";A2;"'!Q41"))
                                =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'";A2;"'!R41")
                                                     =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'";A2;"'!S41")
```

(imagine those formulas in the same row)

with A2=1 (as you drag down the formula its value will be 1, 2, 3 or 4 depending on the table position. It represents the sheet name taken from the first row)

Problem is that when using this formula, dragging down won't change the reference from P41:S41 cells. Is there any way I can have a formula were dragging down the a row gets me P42:S42 from P41:S41 and so on?

Ignore the INDIRECT + CONCATENATE suggestion if there's an easier way to go about doing this.

Comment: INDIRECT is volatile and a sheet full of them will start to slow down the calculation times.  If you go this route I would make sure to put calculations on Manual as any change to any of the table will cause a full recalc of the full summary page and your users will get frustrated.

Comment: You can use the `ROW()` function to increment the row number, and `COLUMN()` to increment the column number.  In row 1, `=ROW()+40` returns 41.  You can convert the column number to a letter with CHAR().  In Column H, `=CHAR(COLUMN()+64)` returns "H".  Hint: capitol A is 65 and the numbers increase through 90 for Z.  Finally, I suggest using "&" in place of CONCATENATE().  In H1, `=CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&ROW()+40` returns "H41".  If you fill that to the right and down, it will give I41, J41...I42,J42, etc.

Comment: Y don't you use the Power Query,,!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have **identical tables** in different worksheets with **same Data Range**, the below written Formula can help to **Merge Tables**.

=IFERROR(INDEX(Comb1,ROWS(A$2:A2),COLUMN(A2)), IFERROR(INDEX(Comb2,ROWS(A$2:A2)-ROWS(Comb1),COLUMN(A2)), "-"))

Before use the Formula in New Sheet, copy the Header Row then place Cell Pointer in **A2 Cell**, write Formula & execute it then drag it right then down till it's needed.

**NB:** Comb1 & Comb2 are two Tables.

**Hope this help you. I've posted the solution after been tested by me.**